# Kendo grid values not being passed to model

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The information a user puts into the grid seems to not actually pass into the model (my theory), returning a `null` value in the controller. I have tried various little fixes, and have looked around it for quite some time, but dont have the experience to see the issue here. Can anyone offer any help here?

**View:**

```
@model Johnson.Billing.Models.TaxService

@using(Html.BeginForm("Save", "TaxService"))
{

<div>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Locations)
    .Name("Locations")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); }).Width(80);
        columns.Bound(o => o.State).Title("State").EditorTemplateName("TaxService");
        columns.Bound(o => o.LocationNum).Title("Loc #");
        columns.Bound(o => o.BasePremium).Title("Base Prem:").Format("{0:c}");
        columns.Bound(o => o.CargoPremium).Title("Cargo Prem:").Format("{0:c}");
        columns.Bound(o => o.InlandMarinePremium).Title("Inland Marine Prem:").Format("{0:c}");
        columns.Bound(o => o.LiabilityPremium).Title("Liability Prem:").Format("{0:c}");
        columns.Bound(o => o.LimitOfLiability).Title("Limit of Liability:").Format("{0:c}");
        columns.Bound(o => o.PropertyContentPremium).Title("Property Content Prem:").Format("{0:c}");
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add a State Tax Calculation"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(model => model.Id(o => o.LocationNum))
        //.Create(update => update.Action("Location_Create", "TaxService"))
))

</div>
<input type="submit" value="Test Taxes" />
}
```

(The create function was something I added in recently that didnt work, so I commented it out for now)

**Model:**

```
    public class TaxService
{
    public string DepartmentType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OriginalTransactionDate { get; set; }
    public int PolicyFee { get; set; }
    public int CompanyFee { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string IncludesWind { get; set; }
    public string CancellationType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TransactionEffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int LocationNum { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int BasePremium { get; set; }
    public int CargoPremium { get; set; }
    public int InlandMarinePremium { get; set; }
    public int LiabilityPremium { get; set; }
    public int LimitOfLiability { get; set; }
    public int PropertyContentPremium { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class TaxServiceController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new TaxService
        {
            Locations = new List<Location>{
                new Location()
            }
        });
    }

    //[HttpPost]
    //public ActionResult Location_Create(Location loc)
    //{
        //var x = new Location();
        //if (loc != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
                //x.State = loc.State;
                //x.LocationNum = loc.LocationNum;
                //x.PropertyContentPremium = loc.PropertyContentPremium;
                //x.LimitOfLiability = loc.LimitOfLiability;
                //x.LiabilityPremium = loc.LiabilityPremium;
                //x.InlandMarinePremium = loc.InlandMarinePremium;
                //x.CargoPremium = loc.CargoPremium;
                //x.BasePremium = loc.BasePremium;
            //};
        //return (null);
    //}

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(TaxService tax)
    {
        using (var svc = new StateTaxService.StateTaxServiceClient())
        {
            var locations = new List<StateTaxService.TaxLocationsRequest>();
            foreach (var location in tax.Locations)
            {
                locations.Add(new StateTaxService.TaxLocationsRequest
                {
```

Same thing with the Location_Create in the controller, I commented it out as it did not work.

I stopped the controller right after the issue area, the foreach statement, where `locations` is null, with the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
In the variable tax, the `Locations` list is also null, bringing me to believe that there arent actually any values in that list.

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

I ended up fixing it by adding a `ClientTemplate` format after all the columns, along with this function placed at the very end of my view:

```
<script>

function index(dataItem) {
    var data = $("#Locations").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
    return data.indexOf(dataItem);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid<Johnson.Billing.Models.Location>()
      .BindTo(Model.Locations)
```

instead of:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Locations)
```